# Pinpointing performance optimizations between gcc-4.1.2 and gcc-4.8.1

Tags: c++, performance, g++, valgrind, kcachegrind

### Context:

I am currently investigating the performance increase between my team's current build environment, which still uses gcc-4.1.2, and a build using gcc-4.8.1.  The results were astounding, with a weighted average of at least 25% speedup across a regression.  I also threw in another test using gcc-4.4.7, but it only saw a weighted average for about 7% speedup.  I had speculated that the large discrepancy was related to the new C++11 copy/move semantics, and since memory transactions were a rather large bottleneck in our program.  We make extensive use of STL types, so perhaps the compiler made good use of their new move constructors.

To verify my claims, I picked a test that showed the average performance improvement, and I ran kcachegrind on it for both compilations.  The results are posted below, and were not quite what I expected.  I should point out a quick and potentially relevant detail.  I had to statically compile gcc-4.8.1's libstdc++.so for bureaucracy reasons. This meant that kcachegrind's locations showed some private libraries that I've censored for safety.

[image]

Much to my surprise, the amount of calls to memory operations was relatively unchanged (`malloc` and `_int_malloc`).  Another interesting result is the completely absence of `memcpy` and the addition of `_memcmp_sse4_1`.

### Questions:

If I wanted to verify my hypothesis that C++11 semantics are the reason for the improved performance, what should I be looking for in callgrind graphs?  Should I find less memory accesses, or should I even find `std::string(string&&)` signatures (which I actually don't find here).  Keep in mind that this is compiled with `-O3`, which might mean that such signatures are optimized out, hence my dilemma.

I am more than happy to report such a large performance increase, but I would like to understand where this performance is coming from.  Let me know if more results need to be reported for more definitive answers.  I hope this isn't too general of a question for SO...

Comment: Your assumptions might be right. I can see that you use `std::string` which can benefit from move semantics. But it is very hard to say without any real code.

Comment: Is there a specific signature to show when a move constructor is being used as opposed to a copy constructor though?  I'm not seeing any difference in the number of calls to `std::basic_string<...>::ctor` or `std::string::_Rep::_S_create(...)`.

Comment: This is beginning to get out of the scope of this question, but gcc-4.1.8 shows far more variety in `std::_Rb_tree` calls, as well as far bigger differences in call frequency (higher for 4.8.1 oddly enough).  Perhaps the speedup comes from a better implementation of maps.  

However, I would like to focus this question on what trends I should look for if I'm trying to find uses of move semantics.  I've tried running small tests that use `std::move` to see what they look like in kcachegrind, however they are all either being optimized out or they simply don't show up as `Foo&&` signatures.

Comment: Yes, you would see the move constructor/assignment getting called. But, as you've said, they're typically optimized out. (that's something you do want)